# CPU Diagnostic Software

Tags: central-processing-unit, diagnostic

Is there any decent (preferably free) CPU diagnostic software out there? It would need to be either *nix compatible or bootable because this is an ESXi server, and does not run Windows or a proper GUI. The only one I know of is the Geek Squad MRI, however, it's technically a "trade secret" so I can't use that at my place of business.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to diagnose? What CPU - and why are you certain that the problem is in the CPU? What vendor is the server from?

Comment: It is a Dell Poweredge T410, with two Xeon processors (either 5500 or 5600, not sure at the moment). vSphere is reporting the following alert: Processor 1 Status 0: IERR Assert

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a support contract (and for any production server hardware, you really should), call Dell. This sounds like it might be related : http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025055

So, it sounds like it might be a known issue. They may also want you to run diags, so you may want to download and run the Dell PowerEdge Diagnostics pre-emptively.

Comment: No support contract AFAIK, this is good to know that this is something Dell may be able to further assist on. I will post back with what I find out.